# How to make userEmail the foreignkey connect to the emailId in Tbluser model

Tags: php, laravel, model, foreign-keys, relational-database

I want to connect the `userEmail` from `Tblbooking` model and `emailId` from `Tbluser` model.

`App\Models\Tbluser`:

```
 protected $primarykey = 'EmailId';
 public function bookings(){
    return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Tblbooking');}
```

`App\Models\Tblbooking`:

```
protected $foreignkey='userEmail';
public function user(){
    return $this->belongsTo('\App\Models\Tbluser','userEmail','userEmail');
}
```

Comment: please put formatted question it looks unclear what exactly you want

Answer (score 1):

App\Models\Tbluser - https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many

```
use App\Models\Tblbooking;

class Tbluser 
{
  public function bookings() 
  {
    return $this->hasMany(Tblbooking::class, 'userEmail', 'EmailId');
  }
}
```

App\Models\Tbluser - https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many-inverse

```
use App\Models\Tbluser;

class Tblbooking
{
  public function user() 
  {
    return $this->belongsTo(Tbluser::class, 'EmailId', 'userEmail');
  }
}
```

---

I would suggest refactoring your code and calling models `User` and `Booking`. You can use `protected $table` to define table that model should use, i.e. `protected $table = 'tbl_bookings';`.

```
use App\Models\User;

class Booking
{
  protected $table = 'tbl_bookings';

  public function user() 
  {
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'EmailId', 'userEmail');
  }
}
```

Also it might be of benefit to have a separate table where you can store all your emails, to follow 3NF ([https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Third_normal_form#:~:text=Third%20normal%20form%20(3NF)%20is,in%201971%20by%20Edgar%20F.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Third_normal_form#:%7E:text=Third%20normal%20form%20(3NF)%20is,in%201971%20by%20Edgar%20F.)). It's also a common practice to use snake case to name columns.